# set attributes inside an object's object using prevState syntax

Tags: reactjs

Each product can be more than one categories so I am trying to create an object of categories inside products object which looks like this:

```
{
"name":"my product",
"categories":{}
}
```

All the categories are displayed in checkboxes. This is how my checkbox change event looks like:

```
const handleChangeCategories = (e, data) => {
    const { name, checked } = data;
    setProductData(prevState => ({
        ...prevState.categories,
        [name]: checked
    }));
};
```

when `handleChangeCategories` is fired, It overwrites entire `prevState` object instead of adding an object in `categories`.

Expected output:

```
{
"name":"my product",
"categories:{"cat1":true, "cat2":true}
}
```

I can achieve it with below code but it does feel `react` way of doing it:

```
const handleChangeCategories = (e, data) => {
    const { name, checked } = data;
    let categories = productData.categories
    categories[name] = checked
    setProductData(productData)
};
```

How do I achieve this with `...prevState.categories` syntax and how do I handle the scenario when if categories is not defined so it should create categories object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you simply want to update the nested "categories" state via checkboxes. Assuming your initial state is

```
{
  name: "my product",
  categories: {},
}
```

Then the following is how you would copy the existing state and nested state. You need to shallowly copy ***each*** level of state that is being updated.

```
const handleChangeCategories = (e, data) => {
  const { name, checked } = data;
  setProductData(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // <-- copy root state object
    categories: {
      ...prevState.categories, // <-- copy nested categories
      [name]: checked, // <-- update the specific category
    },
  }));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Spread the previous `.categories` object into the new `categories` *property*, rather than into the whole object returned to `setProductData`:

```
setProductData(prevState => ({
    ...prevState, // or: `name: prevState.name`
    categories: {
        ...prevState.categories,
        [name]: checked
    }
}));
```